# webmatrix and php directing to another page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple application that I would like to read data from mysql. My index page include simple form to send data to server to process , especially to match data against database.

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">

</form>
```

In the page.php, I do the following

```
define('DATABASE','Users');
define('TABLE','poll');
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root')
define('PASSWORD','');
$conn=mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD) or die("Unable to connect to specified DB");
mysql_select_db(DATABASE); etc
```

But when I submit the form, I receive the 500.0 error message that claims the unmatched ISAPI setup module. I am thinking webmatrix offer all configuration by default, do you have any idea of how to fix this ? Please help.

Comment: What type of product is "webmatrix"? What is an "ISAPI setup module" and how does your described error refer to PHP or MySQL? And what is your concrete question? Your "How to fix this?" refers to the HTTP-500-status, which can have a myriad of causes.

Comment: Are you sure you should be connecting as root? Your database might not like that. Try configuring a user specifically for your application instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
 if(!$conn)
 {
die('Could not connect '.mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db("dbname");
```